# Fire large number of HTTP requests and terminate without waiting for requests

Tags: python-3.x, http, python-asyncio

For some tests, I'd like to fire a large number (~10,000) of HTTP GET requests.

I am not interested in the responses and don't want my application to hang waiting for them, so it can finish ASAP. For this reason my attempt using the `requests` library is terrible:

```
import requests

def fire(urls, params):
    for url in urls:
        for param in params:
            requests.get(url, params=param)
```

How can I send a large number of HTTP requests without waiting for, or processing, responses?

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: @Rob changed this to ask "how" instead of "best method"

Answer (score 2):

You can use `aiohttp` to  fire multiple requests in parallel, followed by `asyncio.wait_for()`.

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp

async def one(session, url):
    # request the URL and read it until complete or canceled
    async with session.get(url) as resp:
        await resp.text()

async def fire(urls):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = []
        for url in urls:
            tasks.append(loop.create_task(one(session, url)))

        # give tasks a second to run in parallel and do their thing,
        # then cancel them
        try:
            await asyncio.wait_for(asyncio.gather(*tasks), 1)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            pass

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(fire([urls...]))
```

Comment: Out of interest (and for the benefit of readers), does this start a request for each one as soon as it is received and rely on OS limits, or does it effectively queue connections after a certain number are already active?

Comment: @halfer There is no queueing, but it can be easily added using the `Semaphore` based technique described [here](https://pawelmhm.github.io/asyncio/python/aiohttp/2016/04/22/asyncio-aiohttp.html).

Comment: OK, thanks. So, the server OS has to handle the connection count overflow if they are created faster than they can finish? I think modern servers can keep track of several thousand at the same time, but there must be a point where it refuses to open another.

Comment: @halfer The OP didn't specify, but I kind of assumed that the connections are to many _different_ servers, e.g. to test the network. Creating thousands of simultaneous connections is in most cases a bad idea, but there are legitimate use cases, such as stress testing. This answer is intended as a starting point, not a complete solution.

Comment: Sure yes, I was just intrigued by how your code works, rather than pressing for more info for the question author. Thanks for the new information. I agree they are probably going to different targets, but they will have the same source server, which presumably can only handle so many outbound connections before requiring the limit to be raised in Linux OS-wide settings.

Comment: @halfer Yes. As the code is completely naïve, if you give it too many urls, it will start raising exceptions (which can and probably should be caught in `one`). The most likely first error would come from exceeding a maximum file descriptor count.